# AttributeError: group

Tags: python, regex, mapreduce

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import re

Creation_date=re.compile('CreationDate=\"[0-9]*\"[:17]')
class Part2(MRJob):
    def mapper(self, _, line):
        DateOnly=Creation_date.group(0).split("=")
        if(DateOnly > 2013):
           yield None, 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     Part1.run()
```

I have written python code for MapReduce Job where CreationDate="2010-07-28T19:04:21.300". I have to find all the dates where creation date is at or after 2014-01-01. But I have encountered an error.

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expression object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects) (the result of [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile)) does not have `group` method:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile('CreationDate="([0-9]+)"')
>>> pattern.group
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object has no attribute 'group'
```

To get a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) (which has a [`group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) method), you need to match the pattern against the string (`line`) using [`regex.search` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.search) (or [`regex.match` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match) depending on your need):

```
>>> pattern.search('CreationDate="2013"')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fac5c64e8a0>
>>> pattern.search('CreationDate="2013"').group(1)  # returns a string
'2013'
```

---

```
Creation_date = re.compile('CreationDate="([0-9]+)"')

def mapper(self, _, line):
    date_only = Creation_date.search(line), group(1)
    if int(date_only) > 2013:
       yield None, 1
```

NOTE: modifed the regular express to capture the numeric part as a group. and convert the matched string to int (comparing string with the number 2013 has no meaning, or raise exception depending on Python version)

Comment: NameError: global name 'group' is not defined. This error appear. How to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: @gd16, I think you didn't code as I suggested in the answer. Could you show your updated code?

Answer (score 0):

`Creation_date` is just a regex.

You need to match your input string before you can call `group(0)`